# About the limit of the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to [0, \infty)$, $f(x)=\lambda(A\cap (-\infty, x))$ as $x\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable such that $0<\lambda(A)<\infty$ and consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to [0, \infty)$, $f(x)=\lambda(A\cap (-\infty, x))$. I would like to compute $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)$.

I have already proved that $f$ is continuous (I have in fact showed that it is Lipschitz continuous), but I am not really sure if this allows me to say that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\lambda(A\cap (-\infty, \infty))=\lambda(A)$. Intuitively, I am sure that this is right, but I am not sure whether the fact that $f$ is continuous is enough to write this. I feel that I am somehow assuming that the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ is continuous in some sense. Could you please tell me if my conclusion is right and if the mere continuity of $f$ is enough for it?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can write this. The reason is the following: if $x<x'$, then $f(x)\le f(x')$ so $f$ is increasing. Also, $f$ is bounded above by $\lambda(A)$, so $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists. Therefore, the limit is equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda(A\cap (-\infty,n))$. Now since $A\cap (-\infty,n)\subset A\cap(\infty,n+1)$ for all $n$, we have $\lambda(A)=\lambda(\bigcup_{n\ge1}(A\cap (-\infty,n)))=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda(A\cap (-\infty,n))$, where we used the following well-known fact:

> If $\mu$ is a measure and $(A_n)$ is an increasing sequence of measurable sets, then $\mu(\bigcup_nA_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)$.

Comment: @JustDropeedin thanks for the proof! I managed to do something similar, but my question was whether the mere fact that $f$ is continuous allows us to write that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\lambda(A\cap (-\infty, \infty))=\lambda(A)$. I would say that it doesn't, but what got me thinking about this was the fact that in the exercise where I encountered this the first question was to prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous and then I had to compute $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x)$. This is why I wondered if there is some connection between the questions or not.

Comment: @MathIsCool Ah I see. I misunderstood:)

Comment: so, I guess that it is correct to say that the mere fact that $f$ is continuous doesn't allow us to write that equality I wrote in my previous comment, right?

Comment: @MathIsCool That is my opinion, I don't see how this is justified by mere continuity of $f$, without mentioning the property of a measure I mentioned in my answer

Comment: thank you very much, I was afraid that I was missing something really easy since I am quite a beginner in measure theory :).